# What is ReactJS's support duration for LTS?

Tags: reactjs, lts

I'm trying to find the documentation for ReactJS LTS (long-term support), including duration and the versions currently supported. I've reviewed their website (https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-versioning.html) and versioning (https://reactjs.org/versions/) but I can't find a clear definition. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe React does LTS versions. They do follow semver though which just means they won't introduce breaking changes without bumping the major version number. [Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-versioning.html)

Comment: And note that major version updates to React typically come with scripts to help you uplift from the previous version, leaving you to do either "nothing" or "very little". If you're multiple versions behind and want to get back to the current version, that means upgrading in several steps to take advantage of the work the React team already did to make uplifts as little work as necessary.

Comment: That is a question more suited for React's git issues tracker or for reddit. In stackoverflow the focus is more on concrete code questions

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [this Github issue comment](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/1745#issuecomment-466767389) from Feb 24, 2019, their policy on support is the following:

> Once a new major is released, we generally stop releasing new fixes for a previous major. The only exception is absolutely critical bugs (including security vulnerabilities).